# Can two adjectives ending in -al be in a row?

Tags: adjectives

I feel like :
Technological Educational Institute is wrong, and that it should be Technological Education Institute.

Please explain if I'm right/wrong, and why?

Comment: This is where tools like [COCA](http://corpus.byu.edu/coca/) really shine. A quick search returns collocations such as *technological total, technological natural, technological medical, technological historical, theoretical social, theoretical temporal, theoretical pedagogical, theoretical natural, theoretical narratological, theoretical political, theoretical physical, physical sexual, physical paternal, physical environmental, physical digital, digital rectal, digital regional, environmental nongovernmental, chemical industrial, chemical mechanical, biological national, national mental...*

Comment: They as much adjectives as any other and follow the same rules.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If it's the name of an actual establishment, use the title the establishment itself uses.

There's nothing wrong in principle in using two subsequent adjectives ending in *-al*, but there's a difference in meaning between 'Technological Educational Institute' and 'Technological Education Institute'. The first describes an institute that is both technological and educational. The second describes an institute that provides technological education.